# Adding leading zeros to date time C#

Tags: c#, string, datetime

What is the best way to add zeros to date time in C#

Example string  "9/10/2011 9:20:45 AM" convert to string  "09/10/2011 09:20:45 AM"

Comment: DO you want to put leading zeros on the `DateTime` object or on the resultant String of ToString() method of DateTime? Thanks :)

Comment: IT is both strings, I do not use DateTime object

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you say, that it is both strings, then you should use the DateTime.TryParse method:

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParse("9/10/2011 9:20:45 AM", out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error while parsing the date");
}
```

Answer (score 16):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") // 12hour set
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") // 24hour set
```

More information / methods about formatting Date can be found [Here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm)

**From you comment**

It's better to use the following to parse a DateTime

```
DateTime date = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime.TryParse("9/10/2011 9:20:45 AM", out date);
return date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
```

You can then check wether it fails by comparing it to DateTime.MinValue rather then crash the application if the Convert.ToDatetime fails

Comment: Because I use only string is this solution ok, 
DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(oldDate);
            String newDate = dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"); thanks

Comment: @SonOfOmer using "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt" is double. HH shows the 24hour time, so it would show 14 if it's 2pm. The tt also shows PM. It's better to use either hh:mm:ss tt or HH:mm:ss.

Answer (score 5):

```
myDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime dt = ...
dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss}", dateTime);`

Comment: I'll give you a few minutes to fix this before I downvote... hint: months/minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Use `string stringVariable = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}", dateTimeVariable);`

Answer (score 0):

just use this code its will help you..

> using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using
>   System.ComponentModel; using System.Data; using System.Drawing; using
>   System.Text; using System.Windows.Forms;
>
> namespace DateTimeConvert {
>       public partial class Form1 : Form
>       {
>           public Form1()
>           {
>               InitializeComponent();
>           }
>
> ```
>     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>       label1.Text= ConvDate_as_str(textBox1.Text);
>     }
>
>     public string ConvDate_as_str(string dateFormat)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             char[] ch = dateFormat.ToCharArray();
>             string[] sps = dateFormat.Split(' ');
>             string[] spd = sps[0].Split('.');
>             dateFormat = spd[0] + ":" + spd[1]+" "+sps[1];
>             DateTime dt = new DateTime();
>             dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateFormat);
>             return dt.Hour.ToString("00") + dt.Minute.ToString("00");
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             return "Enter Correct Format like <5.12 pm>";
>         }
>
>     }
>
>
>     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>        label2.Text = ConvDate_as_date(textBox2.Text);
>     }
>
>     public string ConvDate_as_date(string stringFormat)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             string hour = stringFormat.Substring(0, 2);
>             string min = stringFormat.Substring(2, 2);
>             DateTime dt = new DateTime();
>             dt = Convert.ToDateTime(hour+":"+min);
>             return String.Format("{0:t}", dt); ;
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             return "Please Enter Correct format like <0559>";
>         }
>     }
> } }
> ```

Comment: Why will it help the OP, why should the OP use this? Explain the advantages of your solution, please!